# Search for child values within two dates in Firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how the json looks like

```
"Node" : {
      "1-5-2018" : {
        "10001" : {
          "centre" : "centre_1",
          "name" : "name_1",
          "paidAmt" : "25000"
        },
        "10002" : {
          "centre" : "centre_2",
          "name" : "name_2",
          "paidAmt" : "25000"
        },
        "10003" : {
          "centre" : "centre_3",
          "name" : "name_3",
          "paidAmt" : "10000"
        }
        },
      "2-5-2018 : {
        "10004" : {
            "centre" : "centre_4",
            "name" : "name_4",
            "paidAmt" : "20000"
            }
        }
```

I want to retrieve the values(centre, name and paidAmt) inside the given dates

I've tried using this particular query but it always shows data does not exist

```
Query query = databaseReference1.orderByKey().startAt(fromDate.getText().toString()).endAt(toDate.getText().toString());

                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Data exists within dates");
                            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                Log.d(TAG , "Data are " + ds.getValue().toString());
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Data does not exist within dates");
                        }
                    }
```

Please let me know if it's possible to retrieve all the data within dates. In future i'm planning to add multiple data inside different dates and want to retrieve them based on requirement. Maybe monthly or weekly.

Comment: use TimeStamp  And Use Time As Long Not string

Comment: Have you considered that ordering by date as string in the format d-m-yyyy is not the order you want? if the format was yyyy-mm-dd it might work, but using a real date or long might be better.

Comment: Does firebase allow to store the child value as long? While saving I created the child using datareference.child(date). The child function accepts only string

Comment: okay @JanLarsen I'll try using yyyy-mm-dd format and check if it works. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `fromDate.getText().toString()` yields anything relevant to your date format? If it returns any other format than yours, it will not work.

Comment: I changed the format to 2018-05-01 (yyyy-mm-dd) and yeah the fromDate is also in the same format. It's a datepicker which i'm formatting  now to this format. Still  no snapshot is available.

Comment: @VarunJain Can you please try yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy/mm/dd.

Comment: @KaushalGosaliya Your solution worked. I converted the date format dd-MM-yyyy to long and it started working. Thanks

Comment: @VarunJain if my answer helpful so please correct mark it may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using timestamp instead of a date it may look like this.

```
"Node" : {
      "1525188857" : {
        "10001" : {
          "centre" : "centre_1",
          "name" : "name_1",
          "paidAmt" : "25000"
        },
        "10002" : {
          "centre" : "centre_2",
          "name" : "name_2",
          "paidAmt" : "25000"
        },
        "10003" : {
          "centre" : "centre_3",
          "name" : "name_3",
          "paidAmt" : "10000"
        }
        },
      "1525188873" : {
        "10004" : {
            "centre" : "centre_4",
            "name" : "name_4",
            "paidAmt" : "20000"
            }
        }
```